# Knowing which way to iterate the for loop C

Tags: c, formatting

I want the code to automatically know which way to iterate through the loop without manually adding the '>' or '<' sign. 
I am using the logic that if the setup part of the loop is smaller than the value in the  test expression, then the sign used will '<' and will be '>' vice versa.

The current way I have gone around this is by wrapping the for loop in an if statement, however this looks incredibly bulky and I feel there must be a better way.

The following is the code I am currently using:

```
i = -1;

if ((i*i*i)<(i * i * (i + i + i + i + i))){
    for (integer = i * i * i; integer < i * i * (i + i + i + i + i);integer += i * i * i * i * i) {
        printf("%d",integer);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
else {
    for (integer = i * i * i; integer > i * i * (i + i + i + i + i);integer += i * i * i * i * i) {
        printf("%d",integer);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And here is an example which looks simpler:

```
if (-1<-5){
for (integer = -1; integer < -5;integer += -1) {
    printf("%d",integer);
    printf("\n");
}
}

else{
    for (integer = -1; integer > -5;integer += -1) {
        printf("%d",integer);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the second version?

Comment: Do both solve exactly the same problem? I highly doubt it.

Comment: regarding: `if (-1<-5){`   This will NEVER be true  However, this: `if ((i*i*i)<(i * i * (i + i + i + i + i))){` will be true if 'i' is >0 and false otherwise

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please [edit] to add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a really complicated example with variables, and a simpler one with literals. The literal one is only going to use one branch. So let's do a simple one with variables. Let's say you want to iterate from a to b, but you don't know which is larger. Well, first of all, unless I'm missing something, if a>b, then you'll want `integer -= increment` in the second branch, while your code has `integer += increment` in both. So before your for-loop, define a variable `direction` equal to the sign of `b-a` (that is, if `b-a >0` then `direction = 1`, if `b-a<0` then `direction = -1`). Then do:

`for(integer = a; (b-integer)*direction > 0; integer += direction*increment)`

Comment: Good advice.  I'd write it `int delta = (a < b ? +1 : -1);` and then `for (i = a; i != b; i += delta) { ... }`

Comment: @Edward this seemed to work fine until I came across the initiator being a minus number

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to repeat @Accumulation's solution but instead point out another aspect. By introducing only 2 variables you can make the complicated example look like the simple one:

```
i = -1;
int a = i * i * i;
int b = a * i * i;
// With i * i * (i + i + i + i + i) => i * i * (5 * i) = 5 * i * i * i = 5 * a
if (a < 5 * a) {
    for (integer = a; integer < 5 * a; integer += b) {
        printf("%d",integer);
        printf("\n");
    }
} else {
    for (integer = a; integer > 5 * a; integer += b) {
        printf("%d",integer);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```